# Batch script closing itself

Tags: batch-file, cmd, crash

So, i'm trying to learn batch, and i ran into a problem. I was working on a basic text adventure to learn IF statements and such, and my code is crashing (without an error note) whenever i try to put in the first command, (The input in the ROOM01 label.) this is the beginning -> start of the second label.

```
@echo off
Title =The Temple=
:menu
set progress=0
color 5
echo ===The Temple===
echo
echo *By Dexter Gard, 2015
echo
echo *Public Domain
echo
echo Press any key
pause
echo 
:main
echo ======The======
echo -----TEMPLE----
goto ROOM01
:ROOM01
echo you are in a dark room.
echo there is a DOOR to the EAST.
set/p input=Command?
if %input%==GO EAST goto ROOM02
if %input%==EXAMINE ROOM echo you can't see anything. goto ROOM01
if %input%==EXAMINE DOOR echo A large heavy wooden door. goto ROOM01
:ROOM02
```

Comment: I can guarantee your code generates an error message, but I suspect you are running the script by double clicking it in Windows Explorer, so the window closes before you have a chance to see the error message. You should open a command session, CD to the folder where your script is, and then run the script by entering the name. That way the window will not close when the script ends, and you can then see error messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
set/p "input=Command?"
if /i "%input%"=="GO EAST" goto ROOM02
```

Batch regards a `"quoted string containing separators like spaces"` as a single string. The structure I've shown for the `if` statement is mandatory using strings which *may* contain spaces. The `/i` switch makes the comparison case-insensitive.

If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'`

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use quotation marks both in your code and when inputting the command because they consist spaces, OR you can change `GO EAST` to `GO_EAST`and then you don't need quotation marks. The if clauses also needed some modification to work.

```
:ROOM01
echo you are in a dark room.
echo there is a DOOR to the EAST.
set/p input=Command?
if %input%=="GO EAST" ( 
  goto ROOM02
)
if %input%=="EXAMINE ROOM" ( 
  echo you can't see anything. 
  goto ROOM01
)
if %input%=="EXAMINE DOOR" ( 
  echo A large heavy wooden door. 
  goto ROOM01
)
:ROOM02
```